# Random Forests - Probability Estimates (+scikit-learn specific)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am interested in understanding how probability estimates are calculated by random forests, both in general and specifically in Python's scikit-learn library (where probability estimated are returned by the predict_proba function).

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: I think you're going to have to be more specific than that, particularly, what is your question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The probabilities returned by a forest are the mean probabilities returned by the trees in the ensemble ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)).
The probabilities returned by a single tree are the normalized class histograms of the leaf a sample lands in.

Comment: Do you happen to know where in the docs can I find more info about how probabilities are estimated by a single tree?

Comment: I don't see it currently, we'll add it. You can find it in the literature. It is just the fraction of the samples in the same leaf belonging to a certain class (as I said in other words in my answer above)

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Regarding the way the probabilities are estimated... any thoughts about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002991/how-to-use-whole-training-example-to-estimate-class-probabilities-in-sklearn-ran ?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676634/andreas-mueller)/[Dougal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344821/dougal) said,
when you train the RF, [turn on compute_importances=True](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor).
Then inspect `classifier.feature_importances_` to see which features are occurring high-up in the RF's trees.

Comment: Just a quick note: `compute_importances` has been removed in scikit-learn 0.14+ , feature importances since then are computed upon executing `feature_importances_` (c.f., https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/f7f54244643f68c8ff2640ca0c6c7f0822463a96)